# AngularJS module lifecycle

Tags: angularjs, angular-module

Just googling "AngularJS Module Lifecycle". Could not find anything interesting. Can anybody on the [planet](/questions/tagged/planet) explain me this.

I want to understand how exactly

```
angular.module("ui.bootstrap", [
    "ui.bootstrap.tpls", 
    "ui.bootstrap.accordion"
]);
```

1. How exactly the dependencies gets resolved & in which order they gets loaded.?
2. Does angular first calls run phase for ui.bootstrap then calls
   config and then loads dependencies?
3. (When) Does angular also calls run and config phase for all dependent modules?

Comment: 1) By name as registered via `angular.module`. 2) No, dependencies are bootstrapped first.

Comment: RTFM ~ https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module#module-loading-dependencies

Comment: @Phil thanks ...I need your help in case 3 also

Comment: 3) Yes, during bootstrap

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0/docs/guide/module)

- The modules can be loaded in any order
- Configuration blocks - get executed during the provider registrations and configuration phase. Only providers and constants can be injected into configuration blocks. This is to prevent accidental instantiation of services before they have been fully configured.
- Run blocks - get executed after the injector is created and are used to kickstart the application. Only instances and constants can be injected into run blocks. This is to prevent further system configuration during application run time.

EDIT - update link

Comment: @TributetoAPJKalamSir well that was silly! I've updated as I had intended